# UIScrollView - Custom Map - Prevent marker subview on map from scaling with map

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming, subview

I have a custom map of a limited area, and have it set up to correctly show the users' location.  The map is a 1600px square image within a UIScrollView.

I have a crosshair image to show the current location of the user, which at zoomScale 1.0 is the desired size.  When I pinch and zoom the scrollView, the crosshair scales with it.  I would like to have the subview remain the same size on screen.

I haven't been able to find any information on this, what would be the best way to go about this?

If there is anything I can provide you with to help the answer, please let me know.

Many thanks!

**EDIT -**

Having looked in to this further, there is a UIScrollViewDelegate method `- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale` which I tried using to take the marker's current center and size, then adjust, but this only scales at the end of the zoom.  I would prefer to have the marker remain the same size while the user is zooming.

**EDIT 2-**

Cake has provided a great answer below, but I haven't been able to implement this in the way I imagined it would be.

I have the UIImageView as a placeholder, with alpha set to 0.  This placeholder moves around relative to the map to show the user location.  This operates as I expect it to.  Unfortunately, this resizes with the map, as it is a subview of the map (so it stays in place).

Taking Cake's below answer, I have created the non-scaling crosshair image, and added it as a sibling subview to the scrollview.  The maths, once Cake had pointed them out, were quite simple to get the new frame for the crosshair:

```
    CGPoint ULPC = userLocationPlaceholder.center;
    float zs = scrollView.zoomScale;
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(((ULPC.x * zs) - scrollView.contentOffset.x) - 20, ((ULPC.y * zs) - scrollView.contentOffset.y) - 20, 40, 40);
```

Where the image is 40points wide.  This matches the centers perfectly.

The problem I *now* have is that I cannot get the crosshair image to stay locked to the placeholder.

I have tried using a self calling animation as such:

```
-(void)animeUserLocationAttachment
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.05 
                      delay:0 
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear )
                 animations:^{
                     userLocationDotContainer.frame = newFrame;
               } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     // Call self
                     [self animateUserLocationAttachment];
                 }];
}
```

As soon as I start scrolling/zooming, this locks the animation so that the crosshair just sits in place until I release the scrolling/zooming, then it correctly updates it's location.

Is there any way I can get around this, or an alternative method I can apply?

Many thanks

**EDIT 3 -**

I've re-accepted Cake's answer as it covers 90% of the issue.  Further to his answer I have implemented the ScrollViewDelegate methods `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` and`scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:` to scale the placeholder to match the current size of the crosshair relative to the map, show the placeholder (that is a subview of the map image) and hide the crosshair image.  The delegate method `scrollviewWillBeginZooming:withView:` does not show the placeholder because it scales with the map. As Cake recommends, I'll make a new question for this issue.

The counterpart methods (`scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:`, `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` and -scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`) all hide the placeholder, and re-show the crosshair.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, try looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11228200/1439815. It seems like this is similar to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I had a look at that, thanks for the link.  I've still not got it working perfectly, In the mean time I am making the placeholder the same crosshair image, and when the view is scrolling/decelerating I resize the placeholder to the same as the crosshair, make it visible, and hide it until the motion is done.  This works for movements where there is no change in scale.  Right now I have it completely disappear while zooming is in progress.  I would like to have it so that it scales with the zoom, but might have to settle for this.

Comment: It seems like maybe you should create a new question with the additional problems that have been raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another crosshair image that's associated with the view or view controller that contains the scrollview. Then have this one always snap to the center of the crosshair image you already have. Then, hide your original crosshair image. Then you can avoid having the scrollview scale the disassociated crosshair, and it should stay the same size.

**Relative coordinate systems**

Each view in cocoa touch has a frame property that has an origin. In order to position an object owned by one view properly relative to another view, all you have to do is figure out the differences in their origins. If one view is a subview of another, then this isn't too difficult.

- Get the origin of the container view
- Get the location of the subview inside of the container view
- Get the origin of the subview
- Calculate the difference in the positions of the origins
- Get the location of the object you want to overlap (relative to the subview)
- Calculate the location of the object you want to overlap relative to the container view
- Move your crosshair to this position

Comment: Hi Cake, thanks for your answer, in terms of methodology, this makes a lot of sense, however I am unsure how I would go about snapping one image to another.  Could you point me in the right direction?

I have looked around for positioning one UIView relative to another, and while this is easy enough for static objects on instantiation, the crosshair moves relative to the users position.  Is there a method I can say for the second crosshair UIImage/UIImageView to position it relative to another view that's in a different heirarchy, or is there some kind of animation loop I have to use? Thanks!

Comment: The cocoa touch layer views each have their own relative coordinate systems, and every object that is owned by the view should have a frame object that contains its position. I'll edit my answer to include more detail on how to set up the overlap.

Comment: Ok So I just need to go up and down the view heirarchy! Thank you for your help, Cake!I can do this, and add an animation loop to the visible crosshair to get it to update once a second or so to the new position of the invisible crosshair!

Comment: Just a note as to why I've unaccepted this answer.  This works perfectly for setting a static image in place.  Unfortunately this doesn't help when scrolling. I'll edit the question to reflect my findings.  Thank you for your effort though, Cake, if there is any further help you can provide it will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does happen when you scroll? You may just need to periodically update the location of your crosshair.

Comment: I've edited my question above.  I am updating the position of the crosshair every 0.05 seconds, but when a user makes scroll or zoom action, for the duration of the change in scrollview, the animation does not run, i.e. the crosshair doesn't move with the placeholder.  As soon as the scroll/zoom finishes the crosshair zips across the map to where it is supposed to be.

Comment: I've re-accepted this answer, as it has helped me with 90% of the issue. I've edited my question with further notes.  Thank you for you help, Cake.

Answer (score 4):

The question is old but for the future similar questions I've recently resolved a similar problem applying the hint of Andrew Madsen of another post.
I'had a UIScrollView, with an UIImageView in it. Attached to the UIImageView I had many MKAnnotationView (those are my subviews that I didn't want scaling with the superview).

I did subclass UIImageView and implement `setTransform:` method like here:

```
#import "SLImageView.h"

@implementation SLImageView


    - (void)setTransform:(CGAffineTransform)transform
    {
        [super setTransform:transform];

        CGAffineTransform invertedTransform = CGAffineTransformInvert(transform);

        for (id obj in self.subviews)
        {
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[MKAnnotationView class]])
            {
                [((UIView *)obj) setTransform:invertedTransform]; 
            }
        }
    }

    @end
```

This works perfectly!
Mick.

Answer (score 1):

Swift equivalent for Mick's answer:

```
class MapContainerView:UIView {
    @IBOutlet var nonScalingViews: [UIView]!

    override var transform: CGAffineTransform {
        didSet {
            guard let nonScalingViews = nonScalingViews else {
                return
            }
            let invertedTransform = CGAffineTransformInvert(transform)
            for view in nonScalingViews {
                view.transform = invertedTransform
            }
        }
    }
}
```