# Keeping UIButton relative when zooming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a UIScrollview with a UIImageview inside it showing a floor plan. I also have a UIButton within the scrollview that acts as a marker/pin.

I have implemented zooming with pinching/double tapping on the image, but the UIButton element obviously doesn't move when the image scrolls and/or zooms.

I have tried the following code to try and resposition the button when a zoom is completed:

```
[myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(
                          (myButton.frame.origin.x - myButton.frame.size.width / 2) * _scrollView.zoomScale,
                          (myButton.frame.origin.y - myButton.frame.size.height / 2) * _scrollView.zoomScale,
                          myButton.frame.size.width, myButton.frame.size.height)];
```

This moves the button to the top left hand corner.

Has anyone got any idea of what I should be doing to keep the button relative to the image (the same way a marker does on a Google map).

Comment: Do you want the button to zoom (and not just move)? Did you try adding the Button as a subview of your UIImageView? (Mind setting autoresizesSubviews acordingly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well this was solved by the following:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marker.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(640.0, 230.0, 30.0, 46.0);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.imageView addSubview: button];
self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Basically by adding the button to the imageView directly and then enabling userInteraction, I was able to get all the functionality needed.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a [question very similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11158919/1439815) recently. If you don't need realtime updating (only update when a zoom is completed), then you should be able to use the method outlined here.

Comment: No I don't need the button to zoom - it can stay the same size, just needs to be relative (i.e. if it's pointing to area B on the floor plan, it always needs to be pointing there, regardless of zoom level).

So if I add the button to the UIImageView, it will do this automatically?

Comment: The idea is that you shouldn't directly have your UIScrollView own the UIButton. Instead, have the superview own the button and then calculate the point you want the button to move to.

Comment: Well I have just added the button the the imageView instead of the scrollView, and it is doing all the relative positioning for me automatically! Brilliant!

Comment: ...however, when I add it to the imageView rather than scrollView, this stopps working:

    [button addTarget:self 
    action:@selector(aMethod:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

Comment: Why don't you just connect it in interface builder?

Comment: Solved it with self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Comment: If you solved your question, you should either edit my answer or submit your own answer and accept it, so that future searchers can find what they are looking for.